# Retrieving list of order statuses via Magento API

Tags: api, magento, status

I'm trying to understand if it is possible to retrieve a list of order statuses from the Magento backend via the Magento API. I'm not looking (at this point) to amend the status of an order which is the only answer I've been able to find so far.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have the sales_order.info method or you can retrieve more orders by sales_order.list.

After that you can loop in order array and create a hash map with order ids and statuses.

For array with statuses you need to write your own API method.

See here http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.info.html and http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.list.html

Comment: Thanks Marko

I'm not a developer but a product manager so forgive me if I lack technical knowledge. We have a desktop app that integrates with Magento via the SOAP and REST API. I want the software to be able to mark orders as despatched on Magento. I've been told that this can only be done by downloading the last x days of orders and discovering the statuses so we can compile a list. This seems pretty unwieldy especially if the merchant is a prolific seller. It would also be useful to retrieve the statuses and offer these as a criteria for downloading. Any advice?

Comment: If you want to change order status by you application, you should implement your API method, i.e. sales_order.dispatch. For problem with too many orders you can implement some order XML export for last x days and import to your system by SFTP protocol.